# How to view a default wordpress password if we did not set any

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I used restore and backup to migrate my site from local to a Wordpress site online since it did not work with migrations.
But it changed even the credentials.

Unfortunately, I have not change the login credentials appart from the username and even the email address is still the default one wordpress gives.

I am not able to access my site anymore but only in local since it does not require me to login

Answer (score 1):

You can not *view* a password, as all Wordpress passwords are hashed with a one way hash algorithm. But you can set a new password for that user. If the "forget password" doesn't work for you, put a file named "reset_pw.php" in your web root and add the following lines to it:

```php
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once 'wp-load.php';

wp_set_password('myNewPassword', 1);
```

Where "myNewPassword" would be the new password and "1" would be the user id. Then call that script either from your web browser ([www.yourdomain.com/reset_pw.php](http://www.yourdomain.com/reset_pw.php)) or from the command line (php reset_pw.php). Delete file afterwards.